# How to raise_application_error beyond a when others clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

***Background*:**

I've used a [few Oracle articles](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o33plsql-083386.html) to develop an error package, with some procedures. One of these is **Log_And_Return** which is called throughout the database. I've simplified it for brevity, and it looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE Log_And_Return (error_name)
IS
BEGIN
    // Some code to convert error_name to error_code and error_message
    LOG (error_code, error_message);
    Raise_To_Application (error_code, error_message);
END Log_And_Return;
// In reality, this procedure takes parameters which determine whether it will log and/or raise.
```

The **Log** procedure does as it says and the **Raise_To_Application** procedure simply raises an application error.

**Problem:**

I have a procedure, which performs a query, e.g. fetching a customer record. If this query fails, it's a big problem. So I could do this:

```
BEGIN    
    SELECT *something*
    FROM *some table*
    WHERE *some field* = *some user input*

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    ERR.Log_And_Return('unknown_id');  
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ERR.Log_And_Return('unknown_error');  
END;
```

So I'm displaying a specific error message if no data is found, or a generic one is another problem has occurred.

Now, let's say I amend the code:

```
BEGIN    
    SELECT *something* INTO *some variable*
    FROM *some table*
    WHERE *some field* = *user id*
    Call_Another_Procedure(*user id*, *some variable*)

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    ERR.Log_And_Return('unknown_id');  
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ERR.Log_And_Return('unknown_error');  
END;
```

Now, after the select query, I'm calling a new procedure. Inside it, I'm doing a few things, including an update statement, like so:

```
// bunch of logic

BEGIN
    UPDATE *another table*
    SET *some field* = *some value*
    WHERE *some field* = *variable passed into method*
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    Err.Log_And_Return('some_error')
END;
```

**Question:**

If the *no_data_found* error is thrown, **Log_And_Return** will log the problem and raise an application error... which will then be caught by the *when others* clause in the parent procedure - which will return the wrong message to the user.

**What is the workaround to this?**

One workaround I had considered, and I've no idea if this is recommended or not, would be to wrap every stored procedure with a BEGIN END EXCEPTION block, where every procedure had a *when others* block that just logged and re raised the most recent error (using SQLCODE). Then, in my application layer I could specify that if the error is between -20000 and -20999, show it along with its message, otherwise show a generic message (and the DBA can find out what happened in the database by looking at the log table, along with a full stacktrace).

Or do I simply get rid of ALL *when others* blocks and let the application layer deal with any of these unknown exceptions?

Comment: Which error codes do you use in `Log_And_Return` to re-raise errors?

Comment: @Dmitry: I have a query which calls a table and pulls an error code and error message depending on the name of the error fed to the Log and Return procedure. All of these number between -20000 and -20999.

Comment: This is a multi-post (aka cross-post) of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27040996/272735. Please do not multi-post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Comment: @user272735 Apologies. I was going to delete the original but it had answers so I felt that was inappropriate. Therefore I tried to phrase the question a little differently in the hope it would be "new" enough. I'll not do it in future.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of approaches you could take. You should pick the one you feel is most suitable for your application.

1. Include no `WHEN OTHERS` exception handlers and let the **raw** Oracle errors propagate to your users.
2. Include `WHEN OTHERS` exception handlers in the top-level blocks.
3. Include `WHEN OTHERS` exception handlers in all/most blocks

The first option requires no effort on your part, but can expose users to very unfriendly error messages. They can also expose details about the database which could be of use to hackers, etc.

The second option require some effort. You can use the built-in packages, such as `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE` to identify where an exception occurred, which can be included in any logging processes you may have. You can convert the **raw** Oracle errors into application specific ones.

The third option requires most effort. However, as well as the above, you can also log items such as variable values to help you identify why an error occurred, not just where it occurred. Using some common exception handling routines -as you seem to be doing - will reduce the effort required for this approach.

```
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   exception_pkg.handler('<variable_values_of_interest>')
   RAISE;
```

where you pass the variables values to be logged via a standard process before re-raising the exception.

You should **always** re-raise an exception in a `WHEN OTHERS` block, either the original exception or one with an application specific message - via `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`.

Comment: But how do I solve my issue in the problem above? Using your example, If I raise a custom error message in the subprocedure, the parent procedure will catch it in the "when others" block, change the error message in the "handler" procedure and then raise something different to what was thrown in the original subprocedure. How do I avoid this?

Comment: The handler I suggest would not change the error message, it would merely log any information of interest, such as the `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE` and variable values. If you raised a custom error message - presumably via `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` - in a sub-procedure this would be re-raised as-is in the `WHEN OTHERS` block, and so on up the call stack. The original exception would eventually propagate from the topmost block. I would not have a `Raise_To_Application` call in the `Log_And_Return`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be over simplifying it, but could you use an `IF *some variable* IS NOT NULL` block around the call to the extra procedure? As in, "check to see if the variable I just wrote to is null, if not, do more work, if it is, specifically call my custom error package?

If you've built your own exception handler (and kudos to you for not falling into the "catch all the errors generically" trap), you don't HAVE to call that in an exception block. You can call it whenever you want, and trap the errors whenever they occur.

Comment: I'm actually starting to lean more towards this option. I'm considering actually having all procedure calls in stand alone "begin/end" blocks, so that if any exception is thrown within them it will automatically be thrown back to application layer.

Comment: I think what you're saying could be used to help do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
create or replace procedure p1 is
begin
  select ... into ...
  from ... where ...;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    ...
    raise_application_error(-20100, 'Something not found');
  when others then
    ...
end;

create or replace procedure p2 is
  something_not_found exception;
  pragma exception_init(something_not_found, -20100);
begin
  p1;
exception
  when something_not_found then
    -- after NO_DATA_FOUND exception in p1 this code will be executed
    ...
  when others then
    ...
end;
```

Also you can define exception names and use **pragma exception_init** in package specification.

Comment: The problem with this is I would have to declare an exception for EVERY possible exception that could be raised. And there really will be A LOT (>700 stored procedures)

Comment: @AndrewMartin You can use procedure like errpkg.raise in Steven Feuerstein's article to unite them in groups...